# jquery ajax working in firefox but not in ie when deployed in server but works when executed locally

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working in asp.net website.
The ajax call is working well locally  with both IE and firefox. But, when I deploy the code, the code works fine in firefox but not in IE.
Code:

```
 var sendData=dataString + '$paramtr$' + document.getElementById('<%= hdnUserName.ClientID %>').value + '$paramtr$' + document.getElementById('<%= hdnDataSource.ClientID %>').value;
            $.ajax({
                cache:false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "ConquestLoadSetupMaintainMaps.aspx/PrefillGrid",
                data: JSON.stringify({ carrierfmtid: sendData }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (rValue) {
                    alert(rValue);
                    result = eval(rValue.d);
                    alert("result count :" + result.length);
                    for (var i = 0, len = result.length; i < len; ++i) {
                        PrependRow(result[i].txtDisplayOrder, result[i].txtSourceExpression, result[i].txtClientCD, result[i].chkSkipIfNull, result[i].txtTargetColumnName, result[i].txtCommentArea);
                    }

                },
                error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + "-----" + errorThrown);
                }
            });
            alert("end");
        }
```

Codebehind code:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string PrefillGrid(string carrierfmtid)
        {
            String[] arr = carrierfmtid.Split(new string[] { "$paramtr$" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            if (carrierfmtid != "")
            {
                using (OracleConnection conn = ConnectionManager.GetConnectionObject(arr[2]))
                {
//data fetching code here
                 }
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return serializer.Serialize(list);

        }
```

Please help me if possible. NO idea where I am going wrong.

Comment: are you getting any console error?

Comment: Anoop: NO.I am not getting any error.:(

Comment: what is the network tab showing?

Answer (score 0):

Did a little searching for potential similar issues and came across this - https://forum.jquery.com/topic/fix-jquery-ajax-errors-in-ie.

Give that a try.

Comment: The script which is given,is executing successfully. So this is not the issue which is happenning it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!! I was using IE8. Now, when I open the developer tool, I found the document mode is IE7 standard mode. So, what I did, I used a meta tag in head section stating "IE=Edge" and everything worked. Now IE8 opens in IE8 standard mode and IE9 opens in IE9 standard mode.

The funda which I got studying from web is, for localhost, IE8 opens in document mode, IE8 standard mode. But if it is not localhost and IE8 find IE7 document mode settings, it opens the document in that mode only.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```